# Standard Controller for Account Team Member is not working in a visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement where I need to hide or display a message on click of edit/ delete button of Account Team Member on account related list.
So I am trying to achieve this by overriding delete button using Visualforce page. But it seems like the standardcontroller="AccountTeamMember" is not working.

```html
<apex:page standardController="AccountTeamMember" extensions="AccTeamExtensions">   
    <script>
        sforce.one.showToast({
                "mode": 'pester',
                "title": "Error!",
                "message": "Some message",
                "type": "error"
            });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: no.. it is not moving anywhere.. still on the same page.